# Excel VBA - How to add number of rows based on two cell values and copy/keep data from the third?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created this sample below to illustrate and explain my need. I want to complete the number range between A and B (including A and B) with the result in column A, and keep the data from C for each new row created.

**Current Table:**

```
   A    |    B     |    C     
-------------------------------
0010    |  0015    |   0312
0020    |          |   3500
0029    |  0031    |   4000
```

**Desired result:**

```
   A    |    B     |    C     
-------------------------------
0010    |          |   0312
0011    |          |   0312
0012    |          |   0312
0013    |          |   0312
0014    |          |   0312
0015    |          |   0312
0020    |          |   3500
0029    |          |   4000
0030    |          |   4000
0031    |          |   4000
```

Note: The result does not need to be rendered in the same sheet.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Someone almost solved it but removed their post and I managed to mess it up in the meantime. Can anyone spot the error for me?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim num, i, j, x, lastRow

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

lastRow = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

x = 1
For i = 2 To lastRow
    num = (sh1.Cells(2, 2) - sh1.Cells(2, 1))
        For j = 0 To num - 1
            x = x + 1
            sh2.Cells(x, 1) = sh1.Cells(i, 1) + j
            sh2.Cells(x, 3) = sh1.Cells(i, 3)
        Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

When the above is fixed, the only thing that's missing the last value in column A.
When running this on my example the result in A is:

```
0010
0011
0012
0013
0014
```

It should be:

```
0010
0011
0012
0013
0014
0015
```

Comment: I'm thinking it would be best to do this in a macro. Do you have any experience w/ VBA? If so what have you tried?

Comment: I only have basic experience with macros (recording and simple editing), but not enough to know where to start from scratch.

Comment: I undeleted and updated my answer below since I noticed you quoted it... I deleted it because I noticed that error too, and I didn't have time to fix it. It should work properly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming your data is on a sheet called "Sheet1" in Columns A, B and C, with your data starting from row 2 downward. It will generate your output on "Sheet2":

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim num, i, j, x, lastRow

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

lastRow = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

x = 1
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If sh1.Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
        num = 0
    Else
        num = (sh1.Cells(i, 2) - sh1.Cells(i, 1))
    End If
    For j = 0 To num
        x = x + 1
        sh2.Cells(x, 1) = sh1.Cells(i, 1) + j
        sh2.Cells(x, 3) = sh1.Cells(i, 3)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First you cells format change to the text and you use this code

```
Sub test()
Dim a, rw, b As Long
rw = 1
For a = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Sheet1.Cells(a, 2) = "" Then
        Sheet2.Cells(rw, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(a, 1)
        Sheet2.Cells(rw, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(a, 3)
        rw = rw + 1
    ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(a, 2) <> "" Then
        For b = Val(Sheet1.Cells(a, 1)) To Val(Sheet1.Cells(a, 2))
            Sheet2.Cells(rw, 1) = Format(b, "0000")
            Sheet2.Cells(rw, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(a, 3)
        rw = rw + 1
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This gives me a Run-time error '424' - Object required. 



For a = 1 To Sheet2.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @Ruben change the sheet names

Comment: @Joe Laviano, I have Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3. Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: I think he should have used `Sheets("Sheet2").cells` instead of just `Sheet2.Cells`.